# Python NameError: name 'self' is not defined Why?

Tags: python, indentation, nameerror

***At the top***:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.sprite import Sprite
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
```

***Part not working***:

```
class DetectionBox(Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.img = pygame.Surface([SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT/4], SRCALPHA, 32).convert_alpha()
        self.pos = (0, SCREEN_HEIGHT - (SCREEN_HEIGHT/4)*3)
DETECT_BOX = DetectionBox()
```

***Error***:
NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Someone please explain why this isn't working, because I have no clue. It's working properly with every other class, so it's something about this one.

Comment: Please show the complete error message.  It's possible you have an indentation error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've goofed up your indentation, mixing spaces and tabs. Use `python -tt` to verify.

Comment: *facepalm*  I guess I did. Oops.

Comment: Yeah! pep8 check helped me a lot!